# How do i display data that exceeds a given value?

Tags: vb.net

I have a table with a price and in there has all the prices "Customers" paid so

```
| ID | Price |
|----|-------|
|  1 |  5.00 |
| 50 |  6.70 |
```

I want to make something so when you enter 3 or 3.00 in a textbox then it will show all the records that exceeds that value so since `ID` 1 paid 5 quid then they will show and same with `ID` 50. I want them to display in my datagridview.

What i have so far is:

```
myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter
    myDataSet = New DataSet
    myDA.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand()

    Try
        cmd = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "Select sum(Paid) as total from tblorder"
        cmd.Connection = con
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        myDA.SelectCommand = cmd
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "TTotal")
        TextBox1.Text = CStr(myDataSet.Tables("TTotal").Rows(0).Item(0))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("TTotal").DefaultView
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Use the RowFilter property to show those `Price > x`. Depending on the datasource it might also need a CustomerID filter  The query you have is doing something quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change your code as follows:

```
myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter
myDataSet = New DataSet

Dim price As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text)
'Save the value entered in textbox on the variable price

Try
    cmd = New OleDbCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select ID,Price from tableName where Price > @Price "
    'tableName should be replaced with the name of your table
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", price)
    'Add parameter to pass the price to the query
    cmd.Connection = con
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    myDA.SelectCommand = cmd
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "tableName")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("tableName").DefaultView
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Perfect!

Thank you very much!:)